# Create new list and store data from dictionary for each item instance in dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary where each entry has the items:

```
dict = {'Image': array([[[179, 173, 157],
        [180, 173, 158],
        [179, 172, 158],
        ...,
        [169, 166, 150],
        [175, 170, 154],
        [175, 170, 153]],

       [[176, 170, 155],
        [177, 171, 156],
        [180, 173, 157],
        ...,
        [168, 165, 149],
        [172, 168, 151],
        [170, 166, 149]],

       [[176, 170, 154],
        [178, 171, 155],
        [179, 172, 156],
        ...,
        [168, 165, 148],
        [168, 165, 148],
        [168, 164, 148]],

       ...,

       [[171, 170, 155],
        [169, 167, 153],
        [172, 169, 155],
        ...,
        [174, 168, 153],
        [181, 173, 157],
        [178, 172, 155]],

       [[169, 168, 153],
        [169, 167, 152],
        [171, 167, 152],
        ...,
        [177, 171, 155],
        [184, 176, 160],
        [178, 171, 155]],

       [[165, 164, 149],
        [169, 168, 153],
        [174, 170, 155],
        ...,
        [177, 171, 155],
        [183, 175, 160],
        [179, 172, 156]]], dtype=uint8),
'Value': 159.61, 
'Station_index': 'A',
'Date': 2019-01-07 00:00:00, dtype: float64}
{'Image': array([[[251, 239, 221],
        [251, 239, 221],
        [251, 239, 220],
        ...,
        [250, 237, 218],
        [250, 237, 218],
        [251, 238, 219]],

       [[251, 239, 221],
        [252, 239, 221],
        [252, 239, 221],
        ...,
        [251, 238, 220],
        [251, 238, 219],
        [251, 237, 219]],

       [[251, 239, 222],
        [252, 239, 221],
        [252, 239, 221],
        ...,
        [251, 237, 219],
        [251, 237, 219],
        [251, 237, 220]],

       ...,

       [[250, 237, 218],
        [250, 237, 218],
        [251, 238, 219],
        ...,
        [249, 235, 216],
        [249, 235, 216],
        [249, 236, 216]],

       [[250, 237, 218],
        [250, 236, 217],
        [250, 237, 219],
        ...,
        [250, 236, 218],
        [250, 236, 217],
        [250, 236, 217]],

       [[250, 237, 219],
        [250, 238, 219],
        [251, 238, 219],
        ...,
        [251, 237, 219],
        [251, 237, 219],
        [251, 237, 219]]], dtype=uint8), 
'Value': 356.35, 
'Station_index': 'A', 
'Date': 2019-11-01 00:00:00, dtype: float64}
{'Image': array([[[224, 203, 183],
        [219, 197, 176],
        [204, 184, 161],
        ...,
        [216, 194, 173],
        [216, 194, 174],
        [215, 193, 173]],

       [[221, 199, 179],
        [216, 194, 173],
        [206, 185, 163],
        ...,
        [217, 195, 174],
        [219, 197, 177],
        [217, 195, 176]],

       [[215, 194, 173],
        [214, 192, 171],
        [209, 186, 165],
        ...,
        [217, 194, 175],
        [218, 196, 176],
        [216, 194, 175]],

       ...,

       [[208, 187, 166],
        [210, 188, 168],
        [208, 187, 166],
        ...,
        [171, 157, 137],
        [171, 157, 138],
        [174, 159, 140]],

       [[222, 199, 179],
        [225, 201, 181],
        [218, 196, 175],
        ...,
        [179, 164, 144],
        [180, 164, 146],
        [181, 164, 147]],

       [[230, 206, 187],
        [230, 206, 187],
        [223, 201, 182],
        ...,
        [184, 168, 150],
        [182, 167, 149],
        [187, 170, 153]]], dtype=uint8), 
'Value': 59.19, 
'Station_index': 'B', 
'Date': 2019-06-27 00:00:00, dtype: float64}
{'Image': array([[[181, 177, 168],
        [176, 173, 164],
        [178, 175, 166],
        ...,
        [157, 156, 147],
        [167, 165, 156],
        [163, 161, 152]],

       [[179, 175, 166],
        [174, 172, 162],
        [177, 174, 164],
        ...,
        [172, 169, 161],
        [170, 167, 158],
        [154, 153, 144]],

       [[177, 174, 164],
        [177, 173, 163],
        [183, 177, 167],
        ...,
        [182, 178, 170],
        [181, 177, 168],
        [168, 166, 157]],

       ...,

       [[164, 166, 156],
        [161, 162, 153],
        [164, 164, 156],
        ...,
        [177, 174, 166],
        [176, 172, 164],
        [180, 174, 166]],

       [[169, 170, 161],
        [163, 164, 155],
        [163, 164, 155],
        ...,
        [179, 175, 167],
        [176, 171, 163],
        [178, 173, 164]],

       [[165, 166, 157],
        [163, 164, 155],
        [162, 163, 154],
        ...,
        [181, 176, 167],
        [181, 175, 167],
        [183, 177, 169]]], dtype=uint8), 
'Value': 306.52, 
'Station_index': 'B', 
'Date': 2018-01-01, dtype: float64}
```

I have 50 stations, and i want to create a data frame for the Value and Date items for each station index. My goal is to be able to plot each value list against each date list to observe time series. I know the awful long way to do this is to create a for loop for each station item, but there is no way I can do that for 50 stations. Here is what I have now:

```
value= []
date = []
with open('/JOB/labeled_data.pkl', "rb") as fp:
    data = pkl.load(fp)
    for data_point in data:
         if data_point['Station_index'] == 'A':
            value.append(data_point['Value'])
            time.append(data_point['Date'])

plt.scatter(date, value)
```

Is there a better way to automate this so that I don't have to go in, manually create a new list for each value and date based on station, and manually change what the data_point['Station_index'] is equal to?

Apologies if my Python dictionary terminology isn't correct.

Comment: Can you add a short (but still working) sample dictionary to the post? That would make it easier to provide an answer that fits your use case! Also, do you have just one dictionary or a list of multiple dictionaries, one for each station?

Comment: I've went and added the first 4 entries of my dictionary. And hmm.. I only call the pkl file so it looks like it is just one dictionary, but i am new to python so it could be a list. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Sarah, thanks for the example! Unfortunately I can't paste it into my own terminal directly (because it's not code to *create* a dictionary: see [mcve] for more on this). Maybe let's try another approach: is each dictionary in its own `pickle` file that you're loading?

Comment: Oh man I'm sorry it didn't work. No, i have just one pickle file I am loading in.

Comment: What does the pickle return? A `list` of `dict`s? A nested `dict` of `dict`s Something else?

Comment: I'm quite certain it is a nested dict of dicts.

Comment: Great! Note that your example doesn't create that at the moment. What do you want done with the keys for your top-level dictionary?

Comment: After further inspection, it looks like my pickle file returns separate dictionaries for each date. There is no list `[]` indicator, nor any nested dict `{{}}` indicator. I want to store each date and value instance into a list, separate for each station.

Comment: What happens if you run `type(data)` on the `data` object returned by the pickle?

Answer (score 0):

If you combine your `dict`s in a list, you can use Panda's [`from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) to get them into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

dicts = [{'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 2, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 3}]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dicts)
```

This produces:

```
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
```

Then if you need to access the contents (say of column `a`) as a list, you can simply do:

```
df['a'].values.tolist()
```